# change the background-color of multiple elements with setInterval and arrays in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to change the background-color of multiple elements at the same time. I tried several versions of this code:

```
var indexNumber = 0;

function colorChange(){
var colors = ["#0e76bd", "#aa43a0" ,"#5ad1e3"]; 
//var randColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
$('a, h1, h2, .subhead').animate({'color':colors[indexNumber]}, 1000);
$('.splash, .active').animate({'background-color':colors[indexNumber]}, 1000);
}

setInterval(function() {
colorChange()
indexNumber++
if (indexNumber == 3)
{indexNumber = 0
}}, 1000);
```

This made the colors change, but rather than all the colors advancing to the next sequence in the array, I get a random result where all elements are different colors.

I want all of my elements to change to the same color at the same time. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: You should not rely on global context for value of `indexNumber`, but instead feed it to function directly like `colorChange(indexNumber)`. Doing other way could lead to unpredictable results, like you have now. In addition, you should not use intervals, that you are controlling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot animate colors using default jQuery animation framework. From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animation-properties):

> All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value, except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be animated using basic jQuery functionality (For example, width, height, or left can be animated but background-color cannot be, unless the jQuery.Color() plugin is used).

So the answer is if you want to use jQuery you should also add [jQuery UI animation plugin](http://jqueryui.com/animate/). Take a look at this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/g3QR3/

Here is the [jQuery color](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color/) plugin.

Or instead you could use CSS transitions, that would not require another plugin.

```
var indexNumber = 0;

function colorChange() {
    var colors = ["one", "two", "three"];
    $('a, h1, h2, .subhead, .splash, .active').removeClass("one two three").addClass(colors[indexNumber]);
}

setInterval(function () {
    colorChange()
    indexNumber++
    if (indexNumber == 3) {
        indexNumber = 0
    }
}
```

CSS:

```
.colors {
    -webkit-transition: color 1s ease;
    transition: color 1s ease;
}
.one {
    color: #0e76bd;
}
...
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/g3QR3/1/

Comment: Well, I'm actually suggesting CSS approach better.

Comment: I can't think of a reason for that other than loading another plugin.  Do you have a better reason than that for using CSS approach ?

Comment: Performance, better smoothness of animation are main reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jquery UI to do this.. use interval and css3 animation if you want to animate:

### CSS

```
a, h1, h2, .subhead, .splash, .active { -webkit-transition:color 1s ease, background-color 1s ease; transition:color 1s ease, background-color 1s ease;}
```

### JS

```
var _index = 0, colors = ["#0e76bd", "#aa43a0" ,"#5ad1e3"];

setInterval(changeColor, 1000);

function changeColor() {
    $('a, h1, h2, .subhead').css({ 'color': colors[_index] });
    $('.splash, .active').css({'background-color':colors[_index]});
    _index = (_index < colors.length-1) ? _index+1 : 0;
}
```